# How do I rotate through a collection, causing the layout to change the order displayed dynamically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, partial-views

The title is very awkward, but this is what I want to do.

Say I have 4 images. Each image has two file sizes (`770 x 350` && `370 X 110`) - kinda [similar to this](http://jsfiddle.net/RaDWv/).

What I want to do is to cycle through a collection of `@products` (each `product` has one image with multiple sizes) such that the `770 image` is different on every page load.

i.e. I want to give all the products 1/4th opportunity to appear in the 770 slot of my view - without me manually changing it (by say giving one `product` a special 'featured' flag).

So I have a collection of 4 products, each has 2 images of 2 different sizes. I want the layout of the images on the page to change for every page reload - not like a carousel.

Assume that the two `image_tag` statements I want to use are these:

```
<%= image_tag product.image_url(:main_banner).to_s %>

<%= image_tag product.image_url(:banner_thumb).to_s %>
```

Where `product` is an instance of an iterator cycling through the collection `@products`.

I would love to do it as DRY as possible - I tried doing it with 1 partial, but that is getting messy and not working like I hoped it would.

Let me know if I should add any clarification.

For what it's worth, this is what I am trying:

**Home#index**

```
<%= render :partial => 'home/featured', :collection => @products, :as => :product %>
```

**Home#_featured**

```
<div class="span8 featured">
  <%= image_tag product.image_url(:main_banner).to_s %>
 </div>
<div class="span4" >
  <div class="side-img"><%= image_tag product.image_url(:banner_thumb).to_s %></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ActiveRecord` results is an array, so you can use array methods such as [sample](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-sample) or [shuffle](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-shuffle).

You can pass locals to a partial, such as a randomly selected product from your products collection:

```
<%= render [...] locals => { :featured_product => @products.sample } %>
```

**Home#_featured**

```
<div class="span8 featured">
  <%= image_tag featured_product.image_url(:main_banner).to_s %>
</div>
```

Or you can cycle through the collection randomly:

```
<%= render [...] :collection => @products.shuffle [...] %>
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you very much! I actually went with the sample & `featured_product` version. Even though both are similarly elegant.